# Save Images with orginal name

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, request

I have script to download images from website.
But it's saves name with 'images1, images2, images3, images4 etc'

I need to save images with orginal name. If the images name 43343.jpg
i need to save with 43343.jpg
I use beautifulsoup and requests for this case.

Sorry my english. It's not my first language

````
from bs4 import *
import requests
import os

def folder_create(images):
    try:
        folder_name = input("Enter Folder Name:- ")
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
    
    except:
        print("Folder Exist with that name!")
        folder_create()

    
    download_images(images, folder_name)



def download_images(images, folder_name):
    count = 0

    
    print(f"Total {len(images)} Image Found!")

    
    if len(images) != 0:
        for i, image in enumerate(images):
            

                        
                        
                        
                        

            

            
            try:
                
                image_link = image["data-srcset"]
                
            
            
            except:
                try:
                    
                    image_link = image["data-src"]
                except:
                    try:
                        
                        image_link = image["data-fallback-src"]
                    except:
                        try:
                            
                            image_link = image["src"]

                        
                        except:
                            pass

            
            
            try:
                r = requests.get(image_link).content
                try:

                    
                    r = str(r, 'utf-8')

                except UnicodeDecodeError:

                    
                    with open(f"{folder_name}/images{i+1}.jpg", "wb+") as f:
                        f.write(r)

                    
                    count += 1
            except:
                pass

         
         
         
        if count == len(images):
            print("All Images Downloaded!")
            
        
        else:
            print(f"Total {count} Images Downloaded Out of {len(images)}")


def main(url):

    
    r = requests.get(url)

    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    
    images = soup.findAll('img')

    
    folder_create(images)



url = input("Enter URL:- ")


main(url) ```
````

Comment: Where are the image names in html? Can you confirm the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this part of your code

```
with open(f"{folder_name}/images{i+1}.jpg", "wb+") as f:
    f.write(r)
```

with this:

```
image_name = image_link.split('/')[-1]
with open(f"{folder_name}/{image_name}.jpg", "wb+") as f:
    f.write(r)
```

This will get the last element of your image_path (after the last slash), which should be the name of the image, given the rest of your code is correct and I understood the works of it correctly.

Also, I don't know what your `image_link` variable looks like but maybe you need to replace the `/` with `\\` if your path uses backslashes.

On a last note, consider putting a bit more effort into your stackoverflow questions or your code quality in general. The sheer amount of empty lines makes the code really tedious to read and all the nesting (going deeper and deeper with try-except clauses) certainly doesn't help with that either.

Aside from that, there are lots of better ways to achieve your intended functionality without multiple bare except clauses. In fact, you should never use a bare except statement (`except:` without an exception classname after it). But that's a story for another time.

Comment: Note that this code will override any images with identical image names in your target folder. So, if two images have the same filename, the second one will just override the data of the first one.

Comment: i modified code what you said then it works. only add double .jpg then i modified like this

with open(f"{folder_name}/{image_name}", "wb+") as f:

it works now. thank you.

Comment: Ah I see, makes sense, the '.jpg' is already included in the filename. No problem